# Codesmith resources

Tags: code-generation, codesmith

I use Codesmith to create our code generation templates and have had success in learning how to use the tool by looking at example templates and the built in documentation.  However I was wondering if there are any other resources (books, articles, tutorials, etc.) for getting a better grasp of Codesmith?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you checked the [codesmith community site](http://community.codesmithtools.com/content/Tutorials.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

We also have a great new [collection of video tutorials](http://community.codesmithtools.com/blogs/videotutorials/) available.  You may want to check those out as well.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a [Google Code Codesmith section](http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/) where you can download the latest updates of some CSLA, nHibernate and Plinqo templates.

Comment: Great find!  Thanks for pointing these out, I'm sure I will have a use for them in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting tutorial for [building a data access layer](http://community.codesmithtools.com/blogs/tutorials/archive/2006/02/13/nettiers.aspx) using CodeSmith.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the templates you are using, we might have a separate website with tons of useful information like [nettiers.com](http://nettiers.com/) and [plinqo.com](http://plinqo.com/). Also check out the [help section on our community site](http://community.codesmithtools.com/content/Help.aspx).

We have also recently created a new [WIKI (http://docs.codesmithtools.com)](http://docs.codesmithtools.com/dashboard.action) for all of our documentation.

Thanks

-Blake Niemyjski